# Coldfusion 8 - Which java version should I be using?

Tags: coldfusion, java, coldfusion-8

I'm running CF8 [8,0,1,195765] with java version 1.6.0_14 on a centos VM at mediatemple [2.6.9-023stab048.6-enterpris] & have been having significant problems with 500 errors somehow related to java... I'm wondering if a Java upgrade will help at all. so:

- what is the actual version of java that CF8 expects [supported version?]
- is it safe/tested to upgrade java to the most recent - looks like 1.6.0_26

-thanks
-sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.6.0_24 is officially supported by Adobe now:

[Adobe Technote](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/894/cpsid_89440.html)

Answer (score 0):

It runs OK with 1.5.0_* (under Windows.) You may want to try a downgrade.

Comment: Hi Chris; thanks, I was down that road a while ago, cf8 installs with 1.4.2_14, I tried updating to both [adobe recommended versions] 1.5_13, and 1.6_04 quite some time ago - the update to 1.6.0_14 was in the past 2 weeks.  the 1.6_04 was stable for 6 months or more....